# How to create a media query to change the background image to a different background image?

Tags: css

The site is falboretirement.com. However you need to access it via the link http://falboretirement.com?bypass=jks, because there is a "coming soon" page that otherwise blocks access.  For the desktop version, the hero background image of the happily retired business man jumping in the clouds is the image I want. But, on smaller screens, I want to substitute a solid blue. I've uploaded a blue.gif to the website to use.
 This is a commercial wordpress theme that I am using and I noticed that the theme CSS contains a

```css
.vc_custom_1565817449198 {
  background-image: url(https://falboretirement.com/wp-content/uploads/iStock-638087592_1920X600-60-2.jpg?id=1443) !important;
}
```

which is the code that is setting up the correct background image for large screens.  I'm wondering if the theme author's use of `!important` is preventing me from being able to  override the background image to set it to a solid blue?
I tried using a very specific selector, in the hopes of overriding, but its not working... here is the code that I have tried

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:1024px)  {
  div#freedom-retire.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid.businessman.vc_custom_1565817449198.vc_row-has-fill.vc_row-no-padding.vc_row-o-full-height.vc_row-o-columns-middle.vc_row-flex {
    background-image: url (https://falboretirement.com/wp-content/uploads/blue.gif) !important; background-repeat: repeat !important;
  }
}
```

I also tried:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:1024px)  {
  div#freedom-retire.vc_custom_1565817449198 {
    background-image: url (https://falboretirement.com/wp-content/uploads/blue.gif) !important; background-repeat: repeat !important;
  }
}
```

I verified that the blue.gif is in the folder specified, but I have not been successful.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: looks like you are doing the right thing (!important + specifity increased i guess). are you sure about your mediaqueries ? is this style sheet being loaded last , else it could be overwritten ?

Comment: Remove the space after `url` in your background-image rule, so it reads `url(....)`, problem solved and yes you will need the important tag due to the previous important

Comment: @Huangism  A MILLION Thank yous!  I've been staring at this for > 1 day and could not figure out why it would not work....removing the space after url did the trick!

Comment: You probably looked at it for too long, should get a second opinion if you stare at it for too long and not be able to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you can fix the issue by removing the space between URL & Bracket.

[image]